# matlab run multiple webread at the same time

Tags: matlab

i need to gather five different fast live data feeds from five different webpages. i need my data gathering to happen with the highest frequency possible.
if i run five webreads in a continuous loop, then the sampling rate is to slow as one loop takes five webread execution times.

is it possible to execute all five webreads at the same time so that one loop takes only as much as the longest of the five webread execution times?

code:

```
for i = 1:10000000
    webread1
    webread2
    webread3
    webread4
    webread5
    append latest webread1,2,3,4,5 data to matrix
end
```

thank u!

edit:
i tried something like this but it doesnt make the time any shorter:

```
parfor i=1:1
    webread1
    webread2
    webread3
    webread4
    webread5
end
```

Comment: You would need to use `parfor` to accomplish this and you would have to have each `webread` call the `parfor` loop

Comment: Hi, tnx for your help :)
I dont think i understand how to use parfor thou.
i tried something like this but it doesnt work:

`parfor i=1:1
    webread1
    webread2
    webread3
    webread4
    webread5
end`

Comment: Do you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to `webread` are done synchronously, meaning that `webread` must wait for the response from the server to complete before the next command is executed. If you want to have multiple URLs be read many times at the same time, you'll need to use MATLAB's [`parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) to parallelize the requests.

The following code will execute the 5 different `webread` queries each within their own process such that they can be performed at the same time.

```
urls = {'url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5'};

nQueries = 10000;

% Pre-allocate the output
data = cell(numel(urls), nQueries);

parfor k = 1:numel(urls)
    for m = 1:nQueries
        % Perform the query and store the result in the data cell array
        data{k,m} = webread(urls{k});
    end
end
```